# NSTimer call function from superclass

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

Let's say I have a class Timer that works as a timer.

I want every other class that can act like a timer to have an attribute of type Timer.

The problem is: the Timer class uses a NSTimer attribute and I don't know how to associate functions from outside Timer in it.

For example: Class A has attribute B, which is Timer. How can scheduledTimerWithTimerInterval call some function of A?

Here is timer:

```
import UIKit
class Timer{

    var interval: NSTimeInterval!
    var counting: Bool = false
    var numberOfTouches: Int = 0
    private var timer: NSTimer = NSTimer()

    init(interval: CGFloat){
        self.interval = NSTimeInterval(interval)
        self.counting = false
    }

    func Start(function: String) {
        if(self.counting){
            self.numberOfTouches += 1
            self.timer.invalidate()
            self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(self.interval, target: self, selector: Selector(function), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
        else{
            self.counting = true
            self.numberOfTouches = 1
        }
    }

    func Stop(){
        if(!self.counting){
            self.counting = false
        }
    }
}
```

here is the ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer: Timer = Timer(interval: 1.0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func Trigger(sender: AnyObject) {
        //yes, this doesn't call t() from the ViewController
        timer.Start("self.t")

    }

    func t(){
        label.text = String(timer.numberOfTouches)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Finally, what this timer tries to do is:

- when I press the button, it starts counting and set the number of touches to 1;
- if I press it again, less than 1 second after the touch before, it restart the 1 second timer and increases the touch by 1;
- after 1 second without any touch, it should call t() from the ViewController to set the label to the last number of touches.

What approach should I use to fix this?

Thank you!

PS: in the beginning, it was Selector("Stop")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `"self.t"`, you supply the object as the target.  The selector is something like `"ViewController.t"` or `"t"`.  You need to change Start to take a target object as well.

Move to Xcode 7.3.1 and use the new selector syntax if you can -- it will be type-checked.

Comment: how can I do this? Should I add parameter to Start(var vc: ViewController) and use Selector("vc.t") ?

Comment: I think Start should take a target and a selector. The selector would either be "t" or "ViewController.t", definitely not "vc.t" -- "vc" is the name of a variable that is completely unknown to the Timer -- the selector is applied to the object you pass in as the target.